# Method Passing from one to a different one

Tags: c#, function

this is basically a dumbed down version of what I want to accomplish.
I am trying to tell the program to pass the two methods from different functions to the final one but it says they do not exist in the current context even though I've tried to pass them in Num1 and Num2

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int Option;
    DisplayMenu();
    Option = GetUserOption();
    while (Option != 0)
    {
        switch (Option)
        {
            case 1: 
                Num1();
                break;
            case 2:
                Num2();
                break;
            case 3: 
                Overall(Num3, Num4);
                break;
        }
    }
}

static void DisplayMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. Num1 2.Num2 3.Overall");
}

static int GetUserOption()
{
    int Option;
    Console.WriteLine("Pick choice");
    Option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    return Option;
}

static int Num1()
{
    int Num3;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number");
    Num3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    return Num3;
}

static int Num2()
{
    int Num4;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number");
    Num4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    return Num4;
}

public static int Overall(int Num3, int Num4)
{
    int Overall;
    Console.WriteLine("This will add the two together");
    Overall = Overall + Num3 + Num4;
    Console.WriteLine(Overall);
    return Overall;
}
```

It is still telling me that the params don't exist in the current context.

EDIT: Moved the params into Overall case but still the same error message.

Comment: you have to pass params to your `Overall();` method!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a bit of time to format your code. It's *really* hard to read due to the indentation at the moment. The clearer you make your question, the more likely it is that you'll receive a good answer quickly.

Comment: @Jon Skeet could you please give me an example of how to make it look a bit nicer? Thanks :)

Comment: @Daniel Try an make your code look like it does in visual studio or whatever editor you use.

Comment: @Ben Robinson ...That is what it looks like in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Daniel I've edited it for you, but next time, please try to make it easy to read before posting :)

Comment: @Daniel, looks mlike someone has tidied it for you. If it is formatted in VS like it was originally then I suggest you use the VS autoformat feature. ctrl + k ctrl + D or Edit => advanced => format document. Your life will be much easier with well formatted readable code.

Comment: @WillVousdem Ah thank you, yes that is a lot clearer, I will post all my code in that format in future.

Comment: You haven't specified the scope of your functions - change static void functionName to public static void functionName and it should work. Then read up on whether you should be using public, private, protected etc. This isn't the answer to your problem, but still good practise.

Comment: @Greg I've changed them to public static int and the "The name Num3 does not exist in this current context" still shows.

Comment: @Daniel feel honoured - it's your first post and the first comment was from Jon Skeet. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: There was a person who posted an answer to my problems and it worked but for some reason he has deleted his answer...

Comment: Where have you decelared Num3 and Num4 before passing to overall function? Refer below my answer, my code is working.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a handful of problems:

1. In `Main`, you haven't declared the variables `Num3` and `Num4`, so the compiler is unhappy that you're trying to pass them to the `Overall` method.  You should declare them before your loop (and initialise them to some default value).
2. `iNum3` and `iNum4` don't exist in the `Overall` method.  You've named the arguments as `Num3` and `Num4`.
3. You've declared a variable called `Overall` in the method `Overall` but haven't initialised it, so when you try to do `Overall + iNum3 + iNum4`, the variable doesn't yet have a value.  It's simpler to write `int Overall = Num3 + Num4`.

Comment: Sorry old habits die hard with the "iNum3" and "iNum4" I assure you they are correct and I will sort it out now. Thanks for picking up on it

Answer (score 0):

First off thats not how you would do such a thing its very convoluted and doesnt make sense (took me a while to figure out what you are doing). I still dont exactly know if you are trying to do what i am thinking.

Anyways my guess is you want to add two numbers together and give the user a option at every step if he wants to enter number 1, number 2 or show the current result? Here is a solution where i tryed to keep your style(incase you are learing about switch and function) while maintaining the code. Its still way to "complex" for whats it doing

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int option = 1;
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        DisplayMenu();
        while (option != 0)
        {
            option = GetUserOption();
            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    num1 = getNum(option);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    num2 = getNum(option);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Overall(num1, num2, sum);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1: Num1, 2: Num2, 3: Overall, 0: Exit");
    }

    static int GetUserOption()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pick choice");
        return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    static int getNum(int option)
    {
        if (option == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number");
        return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    static int Overall(int num1, int num2, int sum)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This will add the two together");
        sum = num1 + num2;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Threading.Tasks;  
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
    {
    static void Main(String[] args)
        {
        int Option;
        int Num3, Num4;
        Num3=1;
        Num4 = 3;
        DisplayMenu();
        Option = GetUserOption();
        while (Option != 0)
            {
            switch (Option)
                {
                case 1:
                    Num1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Num2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Overall(Num3, Num4);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    static void DisplayMenu()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("1. Num1 2.Num2 3.Overall");
        }

    static int GetUserOption()
        {
        int Option;
        Console.WriteLine("Pick choice");
        Option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return Option;
        }

    static int Num1()
        {
        int Num3;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number");
        Num3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return Num3;
        }

    static int Num2()
        {
        int Num4;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number");
        Num4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return Num4;
        }

    public static int Overall(int Num3, int Num4)
        {
        int Overall=0;
        Console.WriteLine("This will add the two together");
        Overall = Overall + Num3 + Num4;
        Console.WriteLine(Overall);
        return Overall;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We answered just at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here where the compiler does not know which `Overall` do you mean:

```
static int Overall(int Num3, int Num4)
{
    int Overall;
    Console.WriteLine("This will add the two together");
    Overall = Overall + iNum3 + iNum4;
    Console.WriteLine(Overall);
    return overall;
}
```

make the inner-scoped `Overall` in small case `overall`

```
static int Overall(int Num3, int Num4)
{
    int overall;
    Console.WriteLine("This will add the two together");
    overall= overall + iNum3 + iNum4;
    Console.WriteLine(overall);
    return Overall;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is true - I think the real problem is that Num3 isn't instantiated in Main

Comment: t3ch0t, @Greg is right, this is not the issue. Issue is due to, not decelaring Num3 and Num4. You can refer my edited code, its working.

Comment: @akfkmupiwu sure, I'm not saying it isn't... my assumption was that we perhaps don't see the entire code and I just thought both variables might be declared above the `Main` because @Daniel's assigning values to them so otherwise he must see other errors too.

Comment: Initially i was also thinking the same :)